# Perl script for housekeeping

Tags: perl, pdf

im trying to build a perl script for housekeenping a windows server but it's getting really dificult. so if you guys could help i apreciate.

so...this program shoul find PDF files, zip them and then delete files (outside the zip file) which are bigger than 1mb .

and i think the problem is in the IF filesize condition. so when i put 2 PDF files into a directory, (one smaller than 1mb and another larger than 1mb) , no matter how many times i changed the code this is result:

1. zip all files, delete the pdf files (not those in the zip file).
2. zip all files, delete the bigger file (not those in the zip file).
3. zip the bigger file, delete the pdf files (not those in the zip file).

this is my code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

#1 megabyte = 1000000 bytes

use File::Find;
use lib qw(/st/APPL/PORTABLE/Perl/5.8.8);
use MIME::Lite;
use Strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::DriveInfo;
use Archive::Zip;
use Switch;
use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError);
use File::stat;

#my $backup_root = "/path/to/folder"

my $backup_root = "D:/st/APPL/PORTABLE/Perl/bin/teste";

# purge backups older than AGE in days
my @file_list;
my @find_dirs       = ($backup_root);              # directories to search
my $now             = time();                      # get current time
my $days            = 31;                          # how many days old
my $seconds_per_day = 60 * 60 * 24;                # seconds in a day
my $AGE             = $days * $seconds_per_day;    # age in seconds

find(
    sub {
        my $file     = $File::Find::name;
        my $filesize = stat($file)->size;

        if ( -f $file ) {
            push( @file_list, $file );
            print "Ficheiro $file encontrado!\n";
            print "Size: $filesize\n";
        }

        if ( $filesize >= 1105593 ) {
            #my @files = <*20131221*.pdf>;
            my @files = <*.pdf>;
            zip \@files => 'output.zip'
                or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";

            for my $file (@file_list) {
                my @stats = stat($file);
                if ( $now - $stats[9] > $AGE ) {
                    unlink $file;
                }
            }

            print "Deleted files older than $days days.\n";

        } elsif ( $filesize <= 1105593 ) {
            print "O ficheiro e mais pequeno que 1 mb !";
        }
    },
    @find_dirs
);
```

Comment: Is your5 aim to save space savings by zipping PDF's? Just that they usually have internal compression and wont further compress much.

Comment: yes. but the point it's to automate the ziping file by creating a Schedule task, because this service generates many PDF files a day, some bigger some smaller.

Comment: I think that $File::Find::name holds the name of the current file found, so $filesize holds the size of the current file. Why are you globbing "<*pdf>" inside the "if ($filesize >= 1105593)" block? The globbing and zipping should be done when the current file is a directory and not a regular file, shouldn't it? The code currently zips the pdfs every time it finds a file larger than 1MB.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how output.zip connected with files in $backup_root, but I think that conceptual mistake is recreating zip file inside find callback(=inside loop).

Try following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# purge backups older than AGE in days

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
use lib qw(/st/APPL/PORTABLE/Perl/5.8.8);
use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError);
use File::stat;

my $backup_root = "D:/st/APPL/PORTABLE/Perl/bin/teste";

my @file_list;
my @find_dirs       = ($backup_root);              # directories to search
my $now             = time();                      # get current time
my $days            = 31;                          # how many days old
my $seconds_per_day = 60 * 60 * 24;                # seconds in a day
my $AGE             = $days * $seconds_per_day;    # age in seconds

# get list of all files and directories in @find_dirs
find( sub { push @file_list, $File::Find::name; }, @find_dirs );

# zip all pdfs found in $backup_root directory
my @found_pdfs = grep{/\.pdf$/} grep {-f} @file_list;
zip \@found_pdfs => 'output.zip' or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";

# unlink old big files in $backup_root directory
unlink $_ for grep {$now - stat($_)->mtime > $AGE } grep {-s >= 1105593} grep {-f} @file_list;
```

Comment: i tried did not work. this was the output: zip failed: empty array reference.

Comment: Are pdf files located in the same directory where target zip file should be created?

Comment: I've changed the code to zip pdf files in $backup_root directory.